# Where are recent (post-14.09) Linaro libstdc++.so builds for ARM?

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, libstdc++

The [Linaro GCC FAQ](https://wiki.linaro.org/WorkingGroups/ToolChain/FAQ) specifically mentions `libstdc++.so` as an example of one of the libraries contained by the "runtime" tarballs in release 14.11 and later.

However, none of the releases through 15.05 on [their website](https://releases.linaro.org/) actually seem to include a copy of the ARM `libstdc++.so`.

[tangent about multi-arch `apt` packages deleted as irrelevant]

[first edit deleted as irrelevant]

**EDIT 2:** I just noticed that the 14.11 release `sysroot` *does* contain `libstdc++.so`, which may work. I'm still getting link errors, but they might be due to something else.

**EDIT 3:** I'm closing this question, because I'm no longer seeing the error that inspired me to open it.

Comment: Most of what's here seems to be irrelevant to the problem the title suggests - the issues you've linked to are about running the compiler itself; until the end of last year, Linaro's binary releases were 32-bit (i686) builds, so the GCC executable itself needed a 32-bit libstdc++ to _run_ on an x86_64 system (i.e. nearly everything these days). Since 14.11, the Linux builds are x86_64 only, so that should no longer be be an issue. If you really have a library _linking_ problem, you should post the actual details of that.

Comment: @Notlikethat Oh, I misunderstood the linked questions, then. Yes, I was running the toolchain successfully but seeing link errors. Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact error that caused me to open this question, and I don't see it any more. Currently I'm seeing Boost-related link errors which I suspect may be fixed by re-building Boost, but they could still be related to `libstdc++.so`. In any case, I'll just close this question, since I don't *think* my problem is the Linaro tools.